# docker volumes does not work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose only with a node container to learn and after use another container. 
I have a Dockerfile of node and I share the node folder.

Here is my structure:

```
 - front-end folder
   * docker-compose.yml
   - node folder
     * package.json
     * Dockerfile.json
     * server.js
```

My Dockerfile is the node from dockerhub:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

ENV NODE_VERSION 0.12.15

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt

CMD [ "node" ]
```

And my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: ./node
    ports: 
        - '8080:8080'
    volumes: 
        - ./node:/usr/local/src/node
```

I am can run the command `docker-compose run node npm install any_package`, but when I run the command `docker-compose run node npm install` I receive this error:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.12-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v0.12.15
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
```

And when I run `docker-compose run node npm install any_package`, the folder node_modules should appears at my node folder. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your Dockerfile, it's not clear you are pointing your app to /usr/local/src/node. So your command could be looking for files in a different location.

Assuming your Dockerfile does point node to /usr/local/bin/node, then I suspect your issue is with the host volume. With host volumes, the two most common errors I've seen are permissions with differing uid's and trying to mount folders from the developer machine from inside the Docker host VM. Boot2docker leads me to think you're experiencing the latter. Debug with the following:

```
docker-compose run node ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
```

If that shows an empty directory, then it's mounting a folder from your VM rather than your Windows/MacOS. Use folders in c:/Users (Windows) or /Users (MacOS) to get a share that's mapped into the VM.

If it shows files with different permissions, you can work around that by either opening up the permissions on the Docker host (chmod 777 file) or by making the uid's and gid's inside the container mirror those of your host (this should be done before installing any applications in your Dockerfile).

Comment: I will add my Dockerfile

Comment: With that Dockerfile, it's looking in / for all your files. Using `WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/node` in your Dockerfile, or `working_dir: /usr/local/bin/node` should get you past this error.

Comment: I received this error: `ERROR: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: not a directory"`

Comment: That likely means you have gotten to the second part of the error, above, where ./node needs to be under the /Users folder for the parent OS to VM sharing to work.

Comment: When I got home I try and tell if work =) Thanks for be patient

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` is in `/usr/local/src/node` and `node` (which is ran from `/`) expects it to be in `/`.